# Blazor oauth2 blocked by CORS

Tags: asp.net-core, oauth-2.0, cors, blazor

I have a controller on the server side looking like this:

```
 [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Test(string returnUrl = "/")
    {
        return Challenge(new AuthenticationProperties() { RedirectUri = returnUrl });
    }
```

And when I press a button on the client side i call:

```
await Http.GetAsync("/api/Login/Test");
```

The problem is that I'm getting a cors error in the console and nothing happens. If i put in the url manually in the browser (localhost/api/Login/test) it works fine.

I added a cors policy that looks like this:

```
services.AddCors(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy",
                builder => builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
                .AllowAnyMethod()
                .AllowAnyHeader());
        });
```

and

```
 app.UseCors("CorsPolicy");
```

Which didn't make a difference.

Answer (score 1):

Solved it by using

```
@inject Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Services.IUriHelper UriHelper
```

and

```
 UriHelper.NavigateTo("/api/Login/Test", forceLoad: true);
```